# select data through an associative table

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have  a relationship ManyToMany between two tables (table1 and table2) so i created an associative table .
and then i want to fetch the data with all the details using this function :

```
  async addTable2Details(qb: SelectQueryBuilder<table1>) {
    qb.leftJoinAndSelect('table1.table1table2', 'table1table2')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('table1table2.table2', 'table2')
  }
```

and i get this data in return :

```
{
//other details 
"table1table2": [
                {
                    "table1Id": 1,
                    "table2Id": 1,
                    "table2": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "name1",
                        "disabled": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "table1Id": 1,
                    "table2Id": 2,
                    "table2": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "name2",
                        "disabled": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
}
```

but actually i want it to return directly "table2" without passing through table1table2( which the associative table) this way :

```
{
//other details 
"table2": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "name1",
                        "disabled": 0
                },
                {
                    
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "name2",
                        "disabled": 1
                }
}
```

i tried adding some select fields (to keep the table 1 details and add the table2) in my function this way :

```
qb.leftJoinAndSelect('table1.table1table2', 'table1table2')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('table1table2.table2', 'table2')
    .select(['table1','table2'])
```

but as far i went through the select i noticed that typeorm will always ask for at least one detail of the three tables (in other words if you join you should select some ) .
how do i do that? and if any of my details is wrong i hope to get corrected

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem  **In case anyone gets in the same situation**

i was actually forcing the entities to be mapped to the associative entity , but then i discovered that typeorm uses the associative entity implicitly

for more clarification :
i corrected my entity mapping
first entity:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => table2)
  @JoinTable({
      name: "table1_table2",
      joinColumn: {
        name: "table1_id",
        referencedColumnName: "id",
      },
      inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: "table2_id",
        referencedColumnName: "id",
      },
    })
  table2s: table2[];
```

second entity :

```
    @ManyToMany(() => table1,table1row=>table1row.table2s)
    table1s: table1[];
```

mapping entity :

```
    @ManyToOne(() => table1, table1row => table1row.table2s)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'table1_id',referencedColumnName:'id' })
    table1row: table1;

    @ManyToOne(() => table2, tabl21row => table2row.table1s)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'table2_id',referencedColumnName:'id' })
    table2row: table2;
```

and then i could have just called it directly without passing through the associative table

```
async addTable2Details(qb: SelectQueryBuilder<table1>) {
    qb.leftJoinAndSelect('table1.table2s','table2')
  }
```

hope this helps someone else